# Replacing section in file with sed

Tags: sed

I want to replace a section of the xorg file. Can this be done with sed?

Original Section, i.e. replacing everything between 'Section "Screen"' and 'EndSection'...

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

... replacing with completely new content (multiple lines). E.g.

```
Section "Screen"
    SomeSpecs   "somevalue"
    SomeOptions "somevalues"
EndSection
```

Comment: What should be the criteria to select which of the `"Screen"` sections to replace? Is that the one(s) whose `Identifier` is `Screen0`?

Comment: Basically completely replacing the content. Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Which section? Is there guaranteed to be only one `"Screen"` section or do you want to replace *all* `"Screen"` section with that new contents?

Answer (score 1):

While it could be done with `sed` (more or less easily depending on the implementation of `sed`), using `perl` would be more appropriate:

```
file=xorg.conf
screen_to_replace=Screen0
new_section='    Identifier "somethingelse"
    Device ...
'

perl -0777 -spi -e '
  s{^\h*Section\h+"Screen"\h*\n\K.*?(?=^\h*EndSection\h*$)}{
    my $section = $&;
    if ($section =~ /^\h*Identifier\h+"\Q$screen_to_replace\E"\h*$/m) {
      $new_section;
    } else {
      $section;
    }
  }smeg' -- -screen_to_replace="$screen_to_replace" \
            -new_section="$new_section" \
         -- "$file"
```

Or with `-MEnglish` and some comments for built in documentation:

```
file=xorg.conf
screen_to_replace=Screen0
new_section='    Identifier "somethingelse"
    Device ...
'

perl -MEnglish -0777 -spi -e '
  s{
     ^             # beginning of a line
     \h*           # any amount of horizontal spacing
     Section       # literally
     \h+           # at least one horizontal space
     "Screen"      # literally
     \h*        
     \n            # a line delimiter
     \K            # Keep only what follows from what is matched
     .*?           # anything as little as possibly up until
     (?=           # looking ahead for:
       ^           # beginning of a line
       \h*         # any amount of horizontal spacing
       EndSection  # literally
       \h*         # any amount of horizontal spacing
       $           # the end of a line
     )
  }{
    my $section = $MATCH;
    if ($section =~ m{
      ^           # beginning of a line
      \h*         # any amount of horizontal spacing
      Identifier  # literally
      \h+         # at least one horizontal space
      "\Q$screen_to_replace\E" # "the_old_id", \Q...\E for it to
                               # be taken literally even if it contains
                               # regexp operators.
      \h*         # any amount of horizontal spacing
      $           # the end of a line
    }mx)
    {
      $new_section;
    } else {
      $section;
    }
  }sxmeg' -- -screen_to_replace="$screen_to_replace" \
             -new_section="$new_section" \
          -- "$file"
```

As you mention you want the code of one line for some reason, I take it you don't care much about readability, then:

```
perl -0777pi -e's{^\h*Section\h+"Screen"\h*\n\K.*?(?=^\h*EndSection\h*$)}{($s=$&)=~/^\h*Identifier\h+"Screen0"\h*$/m?qq(    Identifier "somethingelse"\n    Device ...\n):$s}smeg' xorg.conf
```

Here with all the parameters hard coded.

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane. However, definitively prefer a one-liner in sed.

Comment: @Andreas, see edit for a version on one line.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/Section "Screen"/,/EndSection/s/\(Identifier.*\)Screen0/\1somethingelse/' xorg-file
```

If you want to replace inline, you need to add `-i` after sed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked so far! However, I want to replace all lines within this section with some new content, not only a specific value.

Comment: @Andreas please edit your question and explain what you need there. You also need to explain how we can know which of the, often many, `screen` sections should be modified and exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

At first see how `sed` [selecting lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-addresses.html).

```
# print ('p') lines between line that contain 'Section' and line that contain 'EndSection'
sed -n '/Section/,/EndSection/ p' xorg.conf
# to same + line starts ('^') with these text
sed -n '/^Section/,/^EndSection/ p' xorg.conf
# to same + 'Section' line must contain 'Screen'
sed -n '/^Section.*Screen/,/^EndSection/ p' xorg.conf
```

Define our "selecting lines"

```
l1='^Section.*Screen'; l2='^EndSection'
# to same as last command (only for test)
sed -n "/$l1/,/$l2/ p" xorg.conf   # be careful, now use " (double quotes)
```

Finally some replaces (in `sed` "language" substitute `s`). From now always between `$l1` and `$l2` lines !

```
# replace 'Identifier' by 'BLA1'
sed "/$l1/,/$l2/ s/Identifier/BLA1/" xorg.conf
# replace whole line with 'Identifier' by 'BLA2'
sed "/$l1/,/$l2/ s/Identifier.*/BLA2/" xorg.conf
# and finally what do you want
sed "/$l1/,/$l2/ s/Identifier.*/Identifier \"somethingelse\"/" xorg.conf
```